# Pjax получение данных выполнения

Tags: pjax

Выполняю запрос:

```
$.pjax({url: '/message/addmsg?text=&to_id=0', container: '#mesagerightchat',"push":true,"timeout":0});
```

и в контейнере появляется текст, который возвращает акшн.
Но мне не надо обновлять контейнер, надо получить данные из pjax, не обновляя контейнер и самому уже его обработать и вставить.

Есть такое событие:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function(data, status, xhr, options) {  
});
```

Что за переменная data? ну и вообще можно почитать где-то что возвращают события Pjax?

Ну и вот в этом событии:

```
$(document).on('pjax:beforeReplace',function(contents, options){
    return false;
});
```

По идее если возвратить false, то должно отиенчться обновлние.

А как получить что возвращает событие?

Comment: Что такое `pjax`?

Comment: @doox911 отлично гуглится же https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: @andreymal не нагуглилось

Comment: @doox911 у вас сломанный гугл https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Hr7.png

Comment: @andreymal нашел ошибку в запросе)))

Comment: Автору вопроса — всегда можно сделать `console.log(data)` и посмотреть что за переменная, например. Если в документации не описано, то обычно по контексту становится понятно

Comment: зачем console.log(data), я смотрел в отладчике, но суть в том что нет описания этих параметров или я не нашел.